# How to increase limits of years in OpenERP date and datetime field?

Tags: javascript, odoo

I am wondering why OpenERP's date and datetime fields are limited with years?

If I click on year tab to select a year, it shows only 21 years in one go. if I want to select an older year, I am forced to select one older year from the list then it will open next 21 years list for me. It is annoying me.

Is there a way to increase the limit of years so that it is possible to scroll at least into a good range of years like 1950,2020 in one go?

I think I will have to play with javascript but don't know how. Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right I understand your point here, but this is form jquery lib dattime picker yearrange is -10 abd +10 bydefault, But yes for you can increasr to limit you want I have given patch below for the trunk smiler thing als can be done it 6.1 OpenERP

```
=== modified file 'addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js'
--- addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js   2012-10-31 15:03:24 +0000
+++ addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js   2012-11-02 05:08:29 +0000
@@ -2328,7 +2328,8 @@
             changeYear: true,
             showWeek: true,
             showButtonPanel: true,
-            firstDay: Date.CultureInfo.firstDayOfWeek
+            firstDay: Date.CultureInfo.firstDayOfWeek,
+            yearRange:"c-30:c+30"
         });
         this.$el.find('img.oe_datepicker_trigger').click(function() {
             if (self.get("effective_readonly") || self.picker('widget').is(':visible')) {
```

Here you can see to crease the Year range -30 will allow you increase previous year range and +30 will increase upcoming year range. This are lib config can be over rideen anytime.

Thank You.

Comment: How can we do the modification in a customized module? It will be helpful if you give a blog on creating customized modules for web modifications.Thank you

Comment: @OmaL: thsi is very small chnage you can do it gnerioc addons and use it. It is not good to create new module for such small change.

Comment: This one is small, but customizing the new pos view in 6.1 will need more changes. So its better to do the customizations in new module.

Comment: @OmaL: Well Yes I do agree that seperate module nes best way, and if you wanna give a start you here the web dev documentation : http://planet.domsense.com/docs/openerp-web/en/addons.html

Comment: Thanks firebug ,after ask I found it and I tried to reply my question but it said new user cant reply own answer before 8 hours.Well this is prefect answer.